# Can Azure Machine Learning be applied for manipulations?

Tags: azure, machine-learning

I am going thru the samples for Azure Machine Learning. It looks like the examples are leading me to the point that ML is being used to classification problems like ranking, classifying or detecting the category by model trained from inferred-sample-data.

Now that I am wondering if ML can be trained to computational problems like Multiplication, Division, other series problems,..? Does this problem fit in ML scope?

**MULTIPLICATION DATASET:**

Num01,Num02,Result

1,1,1

1,2,2

1,3,3

1,4,4

1,5,5

1,6,6

1,7,7

1,8,8

1,9,9

1,10,10

1,11,11

1,12,12

1,13,13

1,14,14

2,1,2

2,2,4

2,3,6

2,4,8

2,5,10

2,6,12

2,7,14

2,8,16

2,9,18

2,10,20

2,11,22

2,12,24

2,13,26

2,14,28

3,1,3

3,2,6

**SCORING DATASET:**

Num01,Num02

1,5

3,1

2,16

3,15

1,32

Comment: How is it wide? I am looking for training ML to compute multiplication data-set. That is a specific question. Are we flagging the question if it is beyond your scope of answering it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are looking for [regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis), which is supportd by almost every machine learning library, including Azure's services. In laymans terms, the goal of regression is to approximate an unknown function that maps data X to a continuous value y.

This can be any function, indeed including multiplication or division. However, do note that these cases are usually way too simple to solve with machine learning. Most machine learning algorithms (except maybe [linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression))do a lot more internal computations and will as a result be slower than a native implementation on your device.

As an extra point of clarification, most of the actual machine learning (ML) in Azure ML is done by great open source libraries such as [sk-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html) or [keras](https://keras.io/). Azure mainly provides compute power and higher-level management tools, such as experiment tracking and efficient hyper-parameter-tuning.

If you are just getting started with ML and want to go more in-depth, then this extra functionality might be overkill/confusing. So I would advise to start with focusing on one of the packages that I described above. Additionally you would need to combine that with some more formal training, which will explain most of the important concepts to you.

Comment: I shall try regression once.